# Can I bring a motorcycle helmet as hand luggage when flying with Ryanair?

Tags: luggage, hand-luggage, motorcycles, ryanair

I've read about different experiences: someone's being blocked at the security check because "you can hit someone with that", and some others at the boarding because the helmet just doesn't fit with the "small bag" 35cm × 20cm × 20cm allowed dimensions.

Others were able to travel with a cabin bag AND their helmet (they had to put it under the seat in front of them).

Anyone here have an idea of what I should expect?

Comment: Wear it on your head and claim it's a religious piece of headwear :)

Comment: Of related interest: *[Flying with motorcycling gear](/q/65226)*

Comment: Haha, about 20 (!) years ago a former colleague of mine brought a diving belt (tons of lead or whatever) from the US to Europe as carry-on bagage just by wearing it around his body. Where it's supposed to be.
For myself in the same period I carried on a bowling ball (drilled to measure in the US) as additional carry-on luggage. It had to be X-ray-ed twice though.